# how show recently entered text in edit text after entering as suggestion later on using shared preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want an edit text which shows recently entered text as suggestion later on when ever I type different text like phone book in mobile, If first 3 digits or letter matches it shows suggestion and if it does not match the it wont show suggestion. 
 Thanks.

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.onemore);
        srchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
        editText_Acct_Id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.acct_id);
        savednotes = getSharedPreferences("notes",MODE_PRIVATE);

        editText_Acct_Id.setText(savednotes.getString("tag", "Default Value"));
```

This is my on click when I want to save text as suggestion

```
srchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(editText_Acct_Id.getText().length()>0){
                    makeTag(editText_Acct_Id.getText().toString());

                    ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText_Acct_Id.getWindowToken(),0);

                }
```

And thhis method that i called

```
   private void makeTag(String tag){
        String or = savednotes.getString(tag, null);
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savednotes.edit();
        preferencesEditor.putString("tag",tag); //change this line to this
        preferencesEditor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: show us your effort first

Comment: i`ve tried using shared preferences but i couldnt get what i want

Comment: u can save them as an array into a file, or db, and load when you want...

Comment: i`ve edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your EditText->AutoCompleteTextView.
add also store shared preferences data into string array list.
then after used below code like ...

```
        String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_of_countries_name);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);
    mAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
```